# Error filling Elasticsearch with related items

Tags: elasticsearch, laravel-5

In my laravel 5.7 app I use Elasticsearch and I have bulk function to fill my votes with related vote_items.

The problem is that I that I can not add array of related vote_items as I get error :

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"object mapping for [vote_items] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"object mapping for [vote_items] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value"},"status":400}
```

at method(error line is uncomment and marked):

```
    public static function bulkVotesToElastic()
    {
        $elastic = app(\App\Elastic\Elastic::class);

        $elasticsearch_root_index  = config('app.elasticsearch_root_index');
        $elasticsearch_type        = with(new Vote)->getElasticsearchType();

        Vote::chunk(100, function ($Votes) use ($elastic, $elasticsearch_root_index, $elasticsearch_type) {
            foreach ($Votes as $nextVote) {

                if ($nextVote->status!= 'A') continue;   // only active votes must be saved in elasticsearch

                $voteCategory= $nextVote->voteCategory;
                if (empty($voteCategory)) continue;     // only votes with valid category must be saved in elasticsearch
                if ( !$voteCategory->active ) continue; // only votes with active category must be saved in elasticsearch

                $voteItems = VoteItem
                    ::getByVote($nextVote->id)
                    ->orderBy('ordering', 'asc')
                    ->get();
                $relatedVoteItemsList= [];
                foreach ($voteItems as $nextVoteItem) {
                    $relatedVoteItemsList[]= $nextVoteItem->name;     // THIS LINE RAISE ERROR!
//                    $relatedVoteItemsList[]= [ $nextVoteItem->name ]; // THIS LINE RAISE ERROR TOO!
//                    $relatedVoteItemsList[]= [ 'vote_item_name' => $nextVoteItem->name ];   // THIS LINE DOES NOT RAISE ERROR!
                }

                $elastic->index([
                    'index' => $elasticsearch_root_index,
                    'type'  => $elasticsearch_type,
                    'id'    => $nextVote->id,
                    'body'  => [
                        'id'          => $nextVote->id,
                        'slug'        => $nextVote->slug,
                        'name'        => $nextVote->name,
                        'description' => $nextVote->description,
                        'created_at'  => $nextVote->created_at,
                        'vote_items'  => $relatedVoteItemsList,
                        'category_id' => $voteCategory->id,
                        'category'    => [
                            'name'         => $voteCategory->name,
                            'slug'         => $voteCategory->slug,
                            'created_at'   => $voteCategory->created_at,
                        ],
                    ]
                ]);
            }
        });
    }
```

If I uncomment line :

```
//                    $relatedVoteItemsList[]= [ 'vote_item_name' => $nextVoteItem->name ];   // THIS LINE DOES NOT RAISE ERROR!
```

and comment 2 lines above then bulk works ok, but my search condition does not work for vote_items

```
$elasticQuery = [
    "bool" => [
        'must' => [
            [
                "multi_match" => [
                    "query"  => $text,
                    "type"   => "cross_fields",
                    "fields" => [
                        "name^4",
                        "description",
                        "vote_items^2"
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
];
```

and I do not know which syntax is valid?

UPDATED # 2:
Looking at provided docs links I see that:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "user": {
          "type": "nested" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I suppose that saving my data I have to point that some data are nested.

I remade my bulk function into :

```
    foreach ($Votes as $nextVote) {

        if ($nextVote->status!= 'A') continue;   // only active votes must be saved in elasticsearch

        $voteCategory= $nextVote->voteCategory;
        if (empty($voteCategory)) continue;     // only votes with valid category must be saved in elasticsearch
        if ( !$voteCategory->active ) continue; // only votes with active category must be saved in elasticsearch

        $voteItems = VoteItem
            ::getByVote($nextVote->id)
            ->orderBy('ordering', 'asc')
            ->get();
        $relatedVoteItemsList= [];
        foreach ($voteItems as $nextVoteItem) {
            $relatedVoteItemsList[]= [ 'vote_item_name' => $nextVoteItem->name ]; // VALID STRUCTURE ?
        }

        $elastic->index([
            'index' => $elasticsearch_root_index,
            'type'  => $elasticsearch_type,
            'id'    => $nextVote->id,
            'body'  => [
                'id'          => $nextVote->id,
                'slug'        => $nextVote->slug,
                'name'        => $nextVote->name,
                'description' => $nextVote->description,
                'created_at'  => $nextVote->created_at,
                'vote_items'  => $relatedVoteItemsList,
                'category_id' => $voteCategory->id,
                'category'    => [
                    'name'         => $voteCategory->name,
                    'slug'         => $voteCategory->slug,
                    'created_at'   => $voteCategory->created_at,
                ],
            ]
        ]);
```

But looking at mapping :

```
http://localhost:9200/_mapping :
"select_vote": {
"mappings": {
"vote": {
"properties": {
"category": {
"properties": {
"created_at": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"name": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"slug": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
}
}
},
"category_id": {
"type": "long"
},
"created_at": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"creator_id": {
"type": "long"
},
"description": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"id": {
"type": "long"
},
"image": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"is_homepage": {
"type": "long"
},
"is_quiz": {
"type": "long"
},
"name": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"ordering": {
"type": "long"
},
"slug": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"status": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"vote_category_id": {
"type": "long"
},
"vote_items": {
"properties": {
"is_correct": {
"type": "long"
},
"name": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"vote_item_id": {
"type": "long"
},
"vote_item_name": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"vote_items": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

I do not see that vote_items marked as nested, but looking at sample I suppoose it must ?. 
Which is the correct way to write my data that vote_items would be marked as nested ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `vote_items` is nested type field. Something like this:

```
{
  "vote_items" : {
     "type": "nested",
     "properties": {
        "vote_item_name": {
           "type": "keyword"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

This is the reason following works:

> `$relatedVoteItemsList[]= [ 'vote_item_name' => $nextVoteItem->name ];`

To query a nested field you need to use following syntax:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "vote_items",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "vote_items.vote_item_name": "xyz"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the `nested` block having `path` (to mention the nested type field to query on), `query` (the query to run on nested objects). Also note that field name should be fully qualified name i.e. `<nested_field_name>.<property>` which in this case is `vote_items.vote_item_name`.

*NOTE: The above query is example of how to query nested field using fields of your index mapping. Please modify according to your needs.*

For more on how to query [nested fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/nested.html) see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!
Please look at UPDATED # 2:

Comment: Looking at the mapping it is clear that mapping is created dynamically by elasticsearch based on the input data format i.e. [dynamic field mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html). By default if the field holds json object it is mapped to `object` datatype and not as `nested`.  If you want a field to be of `nested` data type then you have to explicitly [create index mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) which defines field and there data type before indexing data.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!
Can you give a hint how to create a mapping in my laravel 5 app as I use
"cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch": "^3.2"

I searched in net and found some articles, like this 
http://elastica.io/getting-started/storing-and-indexing-documents.html 
but I am not sure how to make it with cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch library ?

Comment: Sorry I don't have the idea of the library but mapping creation is one time process. And even if you need to add new field in future, that too may not be too frequent. To create mapping you can simply make a REST call from app to elastic cluster with the required json.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent plugin ?
It has Indexes and Mapping examples like :

```
protected $mappingProperties = array(
   'title' => array(
        'type' => 'string',
        'analyzer' => 'standard'
    )
);
```

If you'd like to setup a model's type mapping based on your mapping properties, you can use:

Book::putMapping($ignoreConflicts = true);